# Why is ODBC not available when I try to create a database connection in DBeaver?

Tags: odbc, dbeaver

I'm following a tutorial to connect to a database using an ODBC driver and DBeaver. But when I try to create a database connection, the ODBC option is not available.

I'm on Ubuntu, using version 22.3.4.202302041940

**Image from the [tutorial](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/access-odbc-dbeaver.rst)**

[image]

**Screenshot of my DBeaver**

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you didn't install the ODBC driver. The tutorial is Windows-based, so the driver would be automatically available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [DBeaver documentation](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/ODBC-JDBC-Driver) :

> This feature is only available in Lite, Enterprise, Ultimate and Team editions.

They are all [commercial versions](https://dbeaver.com/download/) of DBeaver. If you use the [community edition](https://dbeaver.io/), you won't have ODBC available.

Note that you can also extend DBeaver possibilities if you provide a JDBC connector. For example, CData can sell you a [JDBC-ODBC connector](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/bridge/download/jdbc/) that you could then provide to DBeaver.

Otherwise, if you want to connect to an Access database, DBeaver community edition provides the [UCanAccess](https://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) FOSS connector.